# JavaFX crashes when resizing the Window on Mac

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using a Mac with the latest version of Java (FX), macOS as well as IntelliJ IDEA CE.
The problem is that when I resize a JavaFX Window, my Mac crashes instantly. Only when I press the power button for five seconds, the MacBook restarts.
I created a normal IntelliJ JavaFX Project, with these automatically created files:

- HelloController.java
- HelloApplication.java
- hello-view.fxml

I didn't change anything and started the program.
Everything works fine until you try to resize the window, the Mac crashes, you can not move the courser or anything else.

**HelloApplication.java:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

**Hello Controller.java:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label welcomeText;

    @FXML
    protected void onHelloButtonClick() {
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome to JavaFX Application!");
    }
}
```

**hello-view.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>


<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <bottom>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

I have the same issue with the Border Pane (edited with Scene Builder).

**My Hardware:**

- MacBook Pro Mid 2012
- Dual-Core Intel Core i5 2.5 GHz
- 16GB 1600 MHz
- DDR3 1TB Samsung EVO 860 SSD
- Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB
- macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Java (FX) Version:

I tried:

```
java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.runtime.version: 17.0.1+12-LTS-39
javafx.runtime.version: 17.0.1+1
```

And:

```
java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.runtime.version: 17.0.1+12-LTS-39
javafx.runtime.version: 18-ea+8
```

Does someone have the same issue, or know a way to fix this?

Comment: This is hilarious. Try not the latest version maybe.

Comment: @AlexeyVeleshko Ok, it took me while, but nothing helped, I also installed the eclipseIDE. No luck.

Comment: What do you consider to be the latest version of Java/JavaFX? Try using JavaFX 18-ea+8 (or 17.0.2-ea+1).

Comment: Java: 8 Update 311. I tried JavaFX 17.0.1, 17.0.2-ea+1 and 18-ea+8. But I found out that when I resize the window smaller, nothing happens, only when I resize the window bigger as the preferred size, it crashes

Comment: 1.) Java 8 is completely outdated. We are at version 17 now. 2.) None of the JavaFX versions you mentioned is usable with Java 8. Their minimum version is Java 11. So please try again with compatible versions of Java and JavaFX, e.g. Java 17 + JavaFX 17.0.2-ea+1. (The JavaFX version is important because there has been an issue with the previous version which was fixed in 17.0.2-ea+1)

Comment: Ups. I am sorry. Currently I am using Java SDK 17.0.1. I have read it wrong, sorry.

Comment: What kind of Mac is it? Which model?  Which processor (intel or something else)? What OS version does it run?  Edit the question to add the missing information.  As well as the Java/JavaFX version output from mipa's answer.

Comment: Thanks for adding the info.  I have a similar, but newer hardware, 15” Intel MacBook Pro 2017 on Big Sur and the same Java/JavaFX versions.  I have never experienced anything like the issue you described.

Comment: I’m guessing it is an issue with an older Mac.  Normally I wouldn’t recommend older software, but you could try Oracle Java 8 (already includes JavaFX 8 so you don’t need to add additional libraries, but cannot use newer JavaFX features and bug fixes) and see if it works OK.  I think it will as it will have been tested against your hardware and OS versions.  If you do try Java 8 don’t mix it a latter version of JavaFX, just use the one included in the JDK, otherwise it won’t work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have Bootcamp (Windows 10) installed, there it works fine for some reason. I try to clean install macOS Catalina on an external drive, maybe it works there. If it does, I reinstall macOS on my main drive.

Comment: Some news for you. I reinstalled macOS Catalina yesterday. Yeah, it works now. I don't know what exactly the problem was, but it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your example program on my Mac (macOS Catalina 10.15.7). I could make it bigger and smaller without any problem. My Java configuration was:

```
java.vm.name: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
java.runtime.version: 18-ea+29-2007
javafx.runtime.version: 18-ea+8
```

Maybe you should add this init block to your code to make sure that you are really using the version at run-time that you think you are using.

```
@Override
public void init() {
    System.out.format("java.vm.name: %s\n", System.getProperty("java.vm.name", "(undefined)"));       
    System.out.format("java.runtime.version: %s\n", System.getProperty("java.runtime.version", "(undefined)"));
    System.out.format("javafx.runtime.version: %s\n", System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version", "(undefined)"));        
}
```

Comment: I tried:

    `java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.runtime.version: 17.0.1+12-LTS-39
    javafx.runtime.version: 17.0.1+1`
And:

    `java.vm.name: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
    java.runtime.version: 17.0.1+12-LTS-39
    javafx.runtime.version: 18-ea+8`