# How do I use FXML documents in a java project, without creating a new javaFX project? (preferably in eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I want to be able to add javafx to an existing java project to give it GUI. Currently I have to make a new JavaFX project, which I feel limits me.

I have the javaFX SDK and the user Libraries, as well as the VM arguments. I use Java 16 and 17. I always use Eclipse. Am I missing anything?

[image: picture of sdk and user libraries]

Comment: What tools is your existing project using? https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ here are the basics to creating a project. So you need to add the library some how.

Comment: I build them in eclipse using the new java program feature, then I just specify a java version and create a main class. I build on it from there

Comment: In a scratch project, I often put each prototype in a separate `package` and import elements as required.

Comment: So I would recommend looking at the link I posted https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/ That has a section for eclipse. First you install the SDK (which you have done) then you create a User Library then you add that Library to your project. Then you should be able to compile the project, but not run it. You'll have to add a vm argument.

Comment: @trashgod what do you mean by prototype? Does it have some meaning in programming that I am not aware of?

Comment: Prototyping is foundational, as when creating a [mre], for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70531401/230513).

Comment: When you have a new project you just need to add the user library to the new project. Then you add the vm argument to your run configuration. When you do this, do you get any errors?

Comment: @matt I created a new java 17 project, added the javafx sdk, the user libraries, and the vm arguments (--module-path "C:\Users\artur\Downloads\openjfx-17.0.1_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-17.0.1" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml)

I ran it and got this error:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Shouldn't the module path go to the "lib" folder?

Comment: Anyways, you need to add the complete stacktrace to your question. A quick SO check and there is a similar problem, https://stackoverflow.com/a/23133196/2067492 can we see your controller class?

Comment: You can improve the question by editing it instead of writing comments if you wish, when you edit you can quote a question from comments for context if needed.